# How to encrypt a column in Oracle without passing the key to the Oracle Server?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to encrypt a column in Oracle without giving the key to Oracle Server? I need to encrypt a column in my table, but I don't want that the DBA can know the key, is it possible to do this and how ?

Comment: Database Vault allows you to lock down data access to dbas https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/security/db-vault.html

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to do this would be to just encrypt the data from an application connected to your Oracle database.  Then, insert/update your Oracle table, making sure to keep the key away from Oracle.  In terms of where you might want to store the key, Amazon's S3 would be one option, or you could keep it on premise somewhere in a place not accessible by your DBAs.